como escalar un imagen en gimp sin perder calidad
Al descargarme nuevamente Gimp cuando escalo las imagenes pierden calidad, se ven algo menos nitidas que las originales. Por ejemplo sli tienen 964x606 y escalo a 400x251 esta pierden calidad.
Estoy revisando y cuando le doy a la imagen despues de escalarla a exportar como, me aparece el siguiente cuadro de diálogo en el que le doy la calidad máxima del 100%. Yo no se si hay algún parametro que no esta bien configurado?:

Estoy utilizando la interpolación cúbica con la resolución X e Y de 96,000


Hola Jhon, al escalar la imagen ¿que interpolación estas utilizando?

Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no tiene relación con la temática del sitio.

No entiendo por qué cerrar la pregunta, es el apartado de Gimp

@Jhon proba usando NoHalo o Sinc (Lanczos3) (depende de la versión que uses)

Si se cierra la pregunta, debería borrarse también la etiqueta gimp para evitar este tipo de confusiones.

Gracias Marcos en mi versión aparece Nohalo y la imagen ahora aparece perfecta, te agradezco tu gran ayuda. Yo voto por mantener la pregunta, quizás alguien pueda tener el mismo problema y  pueda obtener esta ayuda.

@Benito-B, si bien GIMP no es una herramienta para programar, no veo porque no cumple con la temática del sitio. Por ejemplo, yo me considero programador y es una herramienta que utilizo de vez en cuando. ¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?

Doy las gracias a esta comunidad que ofrece una gran ayuda, si quieren eliminarlo es una opción. Yo al menos el problema que tenía con Gimp ya lo he resuelto.

@Marcos Me voy a quedar con tu "si bien GIMP no es una herramienta para programar" y dejarlo ahí. Si no es una herramienta relacionada con la programación, no tiene cabida aquí. Puedes leer tú mismo el enlace que has pasado, y verás que no dice "herramientas que usen a veces los programadores" si no "herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas", citado textualmente (énfasis mio). GIMP no entra en esa categoría, no importa cómo lo mires. Que exista la etiqueta GIMP no significa que se pueda preguntar sobre su uso sin código de por medio.

"No entiendo por qué cerrar la pregunta, es el apartado de Gimp" -> Tienes la etiqueta de GIMP pero tu pregunta no está relacionada con la programación, temática única de esta comunidad. Si ves la etiqueta tiene 3 preguntas, la tuya, otra incorrecta y luego una de alguien que efectivamente usa GIMP con PYTHON (lo cual es una pregunta válida, puesto que trata de SOFTWARE y no de EDICIÓN DE IMAGEN)

esto es una scala muy alta:  96,000 esto puede contribuir a la perdida de calidad.

me parece interesante la pregunta, ya que como programador web fullstack hay cosas que he tenido que hacer con gimp, ilustrador, corel... para ser implementadas en paginas web ... el hecho de aprender hacer algo que no demora ni 5 minutos en aplicarce ... que es necesario dentro de un proyecto es una ventaja ... ademas no hay un sitio en español en donde preguntar sobre software de diseño o tratamientos de imagen video y audio.

@Benito-B git no es un herramienta para programar, sin embargo las preguntas relacionadas no son cerradas. Por que es eso? Por que se usa para tener un control de versiones de los desarrollos. Con GIMP podes hacer las imágenes (y versiones) necesarias para tus desarrollos, por lo cual, es una herramienta que puede estar relacionada.

@Marcos la idea de los viejos es joder ... no aportan nada a la etiquita y busca joder ... al usuario nuevo ... asi como GIT hay muchos otros software que no deberian tocarce aqui...
